# Node.js not recognizing a require which seems normal

Tags: javascript, node.js

Thre is a file at `/my_project/test.js`:

```
require("processing")
```

And the desiered lib is at:

```
/my_project/node_modules/processing.js
```

It doesn't recognize the library, though. Why?

Comment: `require("./node_modules/processing");`

Comment: That works but I was not supposed to use that when node.js does search on node_modules, right?

Comment: Should...not sure why it isnt?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that - node should find it.  Strange that processing.js is in node_modules - should be just `processing` shouldn't it? (I can't get it to install at all)

Comment: Are you using a package.json manifest?

Comment: Yes, but that processing.js is a standalone file I made myself, because the official processing from npm doesn't work. So I threw it at node_modules. But again, node should find. It works giving the full path.

Comment: If that is the case, it would need to be in a processing folder under node modules and have a package.json that references it as the main file if it isn't named index.js.  If this is just a file you made yourself, you should really be putting it in a lib directory, not under node_modules.

Comment: @dc5 is right. Either put the file in a `lib` directory, or create a `PROCESSING` module and reference the `processing.js` file in `node_modules/PROCESSING/package.json` (or name it index.js)